# Should I always wait for an open chest slot before going to a new battle?

Tags: clash-royale

I'd like to know if there is a sort of "accepted strategy" on whether or not it is worth it to keep battling to get crowns/trophies and miss out on chests (and the potentially sweet, sweet loot within) or is it better to be patient and only battle when I have an open chest slot.

I figured it may be best to wait since the game warns you about it if you try to start a battle without a chest slot, but maybe at a different number of trophies there is a different way to go about it (I am very low level).

I am aware I can spend gems on the chests to open them immediately, but I would rather not do that.

So, is it worth it to only battle with an open chest slot?  Or is it better to focus on gaining trophies/crowns and just keep plowing through the battles to my hearts desire, even if it means missing out on some chests?  (And does the method change at a higher level?)

Comment: what do you mean by miss out on chests?

Comment: I assume that if you go to battle with no chest slots open, and you win, you wouldn't get a chest like you normally would.  Is this not correct?  (I haven't actually tried to battle with no chest slots, saw the warning before battle and thought to ask about it).

Comment: You don't get a chest if you have all your slots filled, but that's it. You can still get crowns for crown chests or trophies.

Comment: Right, that's what I figured... my question is basically is it worth waiting for a slot to open, or do the crowns/trophies more than make up for it.

Comment: The [new update](https://clashroyale.com/blog/release-notes/update-new-cards-more-rewards-live-spectating) that just landed now awards you gold for matches even if your chest slots are full. So, assuming that the the answers about the chests in the drop cycle not being skipped are correct, that would be another reason to keep playing aside from crowns. Also, the Crown Chests contain "twice as much" now, so that might also be a good reason to keep playing for crowns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Battling with no chest slots open doesn't have any real drawbacks. While you can't get a chest if your chest slots are filled, it won't move you in the [drop-cycle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/257513/127901). In fact you can actually use this to your advantage, as you can push to a higher arena or drop to a lower arena before a big chest to have a higher likelihood of getting certain cards. If you move to a higher arena you have the chance of unlocking the new cards from there, whereas dropping an arena can prevent you from getting certain cards from a chest. For example I got my giant chest in arena 5 instead of arena 6, because I didn't want to chance getting 100+ mortar cards that I will never use.

Also, you can still earn crowns to use to unlock your crown chest even if you have all your chests filled.

So if you want to get to a certain arena before a big chest, or if you want to to earn crowns, it's worth attacking with full slots. If you wish to stay where you are, and don't need to get crowns, the only benefit you will get is the fun of playing.

Comment: I had heard about this drop cycle, I suppose I should look into it more.  Looks like a great explanation, thanks!  (I will wait a bit to accept though, just to not rush anything).

Comment: [agent86ix](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/13845/agent86) built a "[Chest Calculator](https://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/clash-royale-chest-order-calculator/)" that you can use to find out where you are in the drop cycle, if you are interested.

Answer (score 6):

As I have [explained elsewhere](https://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/one-quick-clash-royale-trick-i-wish-i-learned-sooner/) - I think playing matches while you are full on chests should be highly encouraged, because the gold and card quantity benefits of each increased Arena are significant enough to offset the statistical odds of getting undesirable cards (despite [persistent myths](https://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/the-most-controversial-clash-royale-exploit/) to the contrary).  In fact, it is better IMHO to leave your chest slots full when you are near an Arena boundary and fight your way one or two wins in, so that you can ensure that your next chest will be from the higher and not lower Arena.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to have your slots full, in order to earn a valuable Chest at a higher Arena, since **chests from higher Arenas contain more cards and gold**.
So, *it's up to you whether if you want that Magical Chest now, or if you want to get it later, **with more cards and gold***.

Answer (score 0):

If you battle with full chest slots, it pauses the cycle.

http://clashroyalearena.com/tips/how-does-the-chest-drop

Answer (score 0):

I agree you will not miss out on any chests battling with full chests, but eventually you will run into players that are a couple levels higher than you with much stronger cards and you simply won't be able to win anymore and will find your max trophy range per level and you should stay there to get more cards per chest and gold to level up quicker