# Chest cycle when slots are full

Tags: clash-royale

If all chest slots are full, does the chest cycle stop until one slot is empty?

Comment: You should use the question body portion of a question to further describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. The purpose of the question body is not to copy and paste the question title into it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes the cycle stops until a slot is available. You won't miss out on any gold or higher chests.

Comment: I thought there was a question about this as well.  Closest thing I found was an answer to [my question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261794/should-i-always-wait-for-an-open-chest-slot-before-going-to-a-new-battle?rq=1) that mentions it.

Comment: Try this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254217/what-cycles-the-player-through-the-drop-cycle?rq=1

Comment: @John I knew I've answered it before!

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, it stops.** If you battle for Trophies, you won't lose that Magical Chest.