# Does Super Magical Chest replace the expected chest from the cycle?

Tags: clash-royale

So it finally happened, after a rage delete and come back I finally just got a Super Magical chest.

What I was wondering, does that drop happen instead of the drop I was supposed to get in the [cycle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254217/what-cycles-the-player-through-the-drop-cycle/257513#257513), or not?

For instance, if I was supposed to get a [Giant at 51](http://clashroyalearena.com/tips/how-does-the-chest-drop) but I got a SM is it true that the next chest I get won't be the 51 Giant chest, but instead the 52 Silver chest?

Comment: I think its like you said, SCM drops instead another chest. I had SCM droped and my cycle continued as it should. But I'm not 100% sure about that.

Comment: @edasssus Shame :( ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consensus from my experience and from [Reddit posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClashRoyale/comments/4hm9at/new_chest_cycle_decrypted_clash_royale_132/d2r1hvu) is that Super Magical chests happen outside of the drop cycle. The next chest that you get will be exactly what you expected to get instead of the Super Magical chest.

In the scenario you painted, you would get the Super Magical chest, then the Giant chest, and then the Silver chest.

Comment: Nice adding the reddit posts (though the poster doesn't go into much detail)